# AngularJS - Parent cannot modify entry pushed to its scope from child

Tags: angularjs

I have two directives, let's call them `parent` and `child`:

```
app.directive('parent', function() 
{
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.baby = [];
            scope.isHome = false;
        }, 
        controller: function($scope)
        {
            Keypress.on('shift && n', function() 
            {
                if ($scope.isHome)
                {
                    console.log('Baby is Home. Feed him.');
                    $scope.baby.feeding = 'yes';
                }
                console.log($scope.baby);
            });
        }
    }   
});

app.directive('child', function() 
{
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        controller: function($scope)
        {
            $scope.takeHome = function()
            {
                $scope.baby = {
                    name : 'My Baby',
                    feeding : 'no'
                }
                $scope.isHome = true;
            }
        }
    }   
});
```

with a very simple HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <button ng-click="takeHome">Take Baby Home</button>
        <span ng-if="isHome">Baby is fed? {{ baby.feeding }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, `Keypress` is a library that calls the callback when the argument is applied. When I press the button "Take Baby Home", and then press "shift" and "n", the console logs the following:

```
Baby is Home. Feed him.
{name : 'My Baby', feeding: 'yes'}
```

But the `child` directive still shows that the attribute `feeding` is `no`. Why? I tried `$rootScope.$apply()` and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Keypress.on('shift && n', function() 
{
    if ($scope.isHome)
    {
        console.log('Baby is Home. Feed him.');
        $scope.$apply(function() {
             $scope.baby.feeding = 'yes'; 
        });
    }
    console.log($scope.baby);
});
```

Angular does not know about Keypress, so calling $apply is necessary to trigger a digest.

Comment: I did.  Still no luck.

Comment: can you post a plunker?